# Proof of a Certain Set Equality

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Sorry for the -- to be fair -- meaningless title but I couldn't come up with a better one. I want to prove that the following set equality holds (or does not hold):
$$ \{\mathcal U:f^{-1}(\mathcal U)\subseteq\mathcal \tau(\mathcal S)\}=\tau(\{\mathcal U:f^{-1}(\mathcal U)\subseteq\mathcal S\}),$$
where

- $f:\Omega\rightarrow X$ is a function and
- $\tau(\mathcal S)$ denotes a topology generated by a subbase $\mathcal S$

There is a similar result for the "induced topology": $f^{-1}(\tau(\mathcal S)) = \tau(f^{-1}(\mathcal S))$ and I belive that a similar theorem also holds for the so called "coinduced topology".

I could already prove that $\tau(\{\mathcal U:f^{-1}(\mathcal U)\subseteq\mathcal S\})\subseteq\{\mathcal U:f^{-1}(\mathcal U)\subseteq\tau(\mathcal S)\}$ (since $\{\mathcal U:f^{-1}(\mathcal U)\subseteq\mathcal S\}\subseteq\{\mathcal U:f^{-1}(\mathcal U)\subseteq\tau(\mathcal S)\}$ by monotony of preimage and since the left hand side is already a topology, it the result follows by applying the $\tau$ operator) but "$\supseteq$" is missing and I have not idea how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first equality in your question on the right side is a topology, that is a family of subset of $\Omega$, whereas at the left side is a family of families of subsets.

So I guess that you wanted to ask whether $ \{ U:f^{-1}(U)\in\mathcal \tau(\mathcal S)\}=\tau(\{U:f^{-1}(U)\in\mathcal S\})?$

If the map $f$ is surjective then the left hand side of the equality defines the quotient topology $\tau_f$ on the set $X$. So if $U\subset X$ and $f^{-1}(U)\in\mathcal S$ then $U\in\tau_f$. Therefore the right hand side (provided it exists) is contained in the left hand side.

But the converse inclusion not always holds, because the elements of $\mathcal S$ can be not pre-images of subsets of $X$ even for surjective $f$. For instance, let $\Omega$ be the real plane $\Bbb R^2$ endowed with the usual topology, $\mathcal S$ be a subbase of $\Bbb R^2$ consisting of open squares, and $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ be the projection onto the first coordinate. In this case $\{ U:f^{-1}(U)\in\mathcal \tau(\mathcal S)\}$ is the usual topology of the real line, but the family $\{U:f^{-1}(U)\in\mathcal S\}$ is empty.